# Applying sklearn TFIDF returns an unexpected dataframe shape

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am applying TFIDF over a feature matrix of dimension (590295, 6) with max_features configured = 10000 but the output dataframe shape is  (6, 6) while I was expecting it to be (590295, 10000). This is happening within the following method. Note that Previously, the code was working outside the method:

```
def ApplyTFIDF(self,cleaned_data_set, max_features):
        print "in TFIDF", max_features
        vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = "word", tokenizer = None, preprocessor = None, stop_words = None, max_features = max_features) 
        print "in TFIDF cleaned_data_set", cleaned_data_set.shape 
        dataset_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(cleaned_data_set)

        print "in TFIDF, after fit_transform", dataset_features.shape 

        return dataset_features
```

The output:

```
cleaned_data_set shape (590295, 6)
in TFIDF 10000
in TFIDF cleaned_data_set (590295, 6)
in TFIDF, after fit_transform (6, 6)
after TFIDF (6, 6)
```

Further information:

I am working with a dataframe holding the data of a csv file. I am extracting few columns of this dataframe into the cleaned_data_set variable with the following code:

```
cleaned_data_set = data_set[listOfAttributeColumnNames]
```

where listOfAttributeColumnNames is a list of column names. Previously, I was doing that with the following hardcoded command:

```
cleaned_data_set = data_set.ColumnName1.map(str)+" "+data_set.ColumnName2.map(str)+ " " + data_set.ColumnName3.map(str)+" " + data_set.ColumnName4.map(str) + " " + data_set.ColumnName5.map(str)+ " " + data_set.ColumnName6.map(str)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: TfidfVectorizer expects text so I don't see why it does not raise an error here. I can't reproduce your behaviour on small test cases (I'm getting an error, which I think is right ;)). What's in your array?

Comment: @user3914041, thanks for your help. I updated my question with some other processing I am using to extract some data columns of the dataframe, I think what I am missing is the datatype of the columns after the slicing operations. Please check I let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I am confused in how does `cleaned_data_set` has 6 columns

Comment: @yangjie, thanks for helping! I did not include all the columns in the cleaned_data_set is constructed. Sorry.

Comment: @MedAli I know you did not include all the columns, but since you concatenated the strings, each row should be a single string, right?

Comment: @yangjie, yes indeed, now I see my mistake: switching from the hardcoded to the rather more dynamic version, I foreget to do the concatenation, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TfidfVectorizer` takes the *text* content as input.
So for your use case you need to pass a vector with 590295 elements: the text (string) you want to vectorize.

You give it a 6-column Dataframe: where or what is the text it is supposed to vectorize? I am surprised you're not getting an error.

These two commands you used for preprocessing are **very different**:

```
cleaned_data_set = data_set[listOfAttributeColumnNames]
```

This gives you a dataframe with `len(listOfAttributeColumnNames)` (apparently 6) columns. This is not a proper input for the vectorizer as I mentioned.

```
cleaned_data_set = data_set.ColumnName1.map(str)+" "+data_set.ColumnName2.map(str)+ " " + data_set.ColumnName3.map(str)
```

This gives you a Series object, that can be seen as a column vector **with String elements**. This is a proper input for `TfidfVectorizer`.

You could do something along the lines of:

```
cleaned_data_set = data_set.apply(lambda x: " ".join([str(el) for el in x[["ColumnName1", "ColumnName2", "ColumnName3"]]]), axis=1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the join of the columns after refactoring my code.